# Krull dimension of the ring of global sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme. Can the Krull dimension of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ exceed that of $X$?

Comment: See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this happens if $X$ is the punctured spectrum of a two dimensional regular local ring.

Comment: what is the Krull dimension of such $X$? I believe $X$ has closed points, so puncturing should not really change anything, right?

Comment: @schematic_boi The Krull dimension of $X$ is $1$.

Comment: can this happen if $X$ is a scheme locally of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$? $X$ of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$?