# Krull dimension of schemes locally of finite type over PID

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring that is a PID. Assume that $R$ is not a DVR. Let $X$ be an integral scheme locally of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}\,R$. Can the Krull dimension of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ exceed that of $X$? This is [not true](https://mathoverflow.net/a/330736/138661) if we drop all assumptions on $X$.